# Pass by reference or by value?

Tags: apex

Take a look at the code below, here i am trying to add into a map of string and a list of opportunitylineitems. I seem to get in all nodes of the map the same list of oli, whichever was processed last.

Whatever is there in familyoli is same for all the map keys. Is there a way these are passed by value into map and not as reference

```
public Map<String,List<opportunityLineItem>>  familyMap {get; set;}
familyMap.clear(); 
    for(Integer i =0; i < selectedOpportunityLineItem.size(); i++)
    {

        if (familyMap.containsKey(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family))
        {

            system.debug('No of lineitems for the family before getting from map' + selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family + oliFamily.size());

            system.debug('This family exists in map for opp product ' + selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.name);
            oliFamily = familyMap.get(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family);
            system.debug('No of lineitems for the family ' + selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family + oliFamily.size());
            oliFamily.add(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i]);
            familyMap.put(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family, oliFamily);
        }
        else 
        {

            system.debug('This family does not exists in map for product' + selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.name);
            oliFamily.add(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i]);
            familyMap.put(selectedOpportunityLineItem[i].PriceBookEntry.Product2.Family, oliFamily);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you perform a `clone` or `deepClone` on items before each `map.put`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about performing a [clone](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#d484880e218) or [deepClone](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#d484880e252) on the items before each `map.put`?